# Why is python not using my PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.3, pythonpath

I cannot figure out why my python installation is not using the PYTHONPATH environment variable. I'm running Python 3.3 on Mac OS X 10.9.2. Here's my PYTHONPATH and the problem that it doesn't show up in sys.path.

```
~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/path/to/dir
~$ python
Python 3.3.3 (default, Dec 30 2013, 23:51:18) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3...', ..., '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/...']
```

Any clue where to start looking for a solution?

Comment: What is the output of `python -c 'import inspect; import site; print inspect.getfile(site)'`?  The `site` module is supposed to read PYTHONPATH, but there may be another that is shadowing the one in `site-packages`.

Comment: python -c 'import inspect; import site; print(inspect.getfile(site))' outputs 
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site.py

Comment: If you do a `grep PYTHONPATH` on that file, do you get a hit?  Is there also a `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/pyt‌​hon3.3/site-packages/site.py`?

Comment: Why would one downvote this?  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: No hits on grep for the first file, but the second gives what looks like the right code for appending PYTHONPATH. What is going on here?

Comment: Is the `site-packages` folder in the output of `sys.path`?

Comment: Check `which python` and (while `python` is executing) `ps -Eww $PID`.

Comment: Here's the complete output: http://pastebin.com/kVEbFUUV  It looks like there are some eggs in the right directory in sys.path, and the parent directory of site-packages, and some other directories like /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages

Comment: I may have just sent you down a bad path.  The `site-packages/site.py` file is loaded by python in the internal C code, not dynamically as a module.  Are you sure that `/path/to/dir` is not in `sys.path`? It might be buried in the middle there (it is on my machine).  Try `>>> '/path/to/dir' in sys.path`.

Comment: When you set PYTHONPATH, did you do an `export`?

Comment: It is definitely not.

Comment: Yes to exporting the PYTHONPATH. here is my .profile: http://pastebin.com/T5quygQT and echoing $PYTHONPATH gives what I expect, as in the original text.

Comment: It looks like you installed with homebrew.  They may have done something to make python look for a different variable name to differentiate 2.x and 3.x.  What happens if you set PYTHON3PATH?

Comment: Still nothing... But I will look now for existing homebrew problems.

Comment: There appears to be a site.py in the homebrew site-packages directory that loads PYTHONPATH, but I put a print statement in the file and it never gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I fully understand the question but one possibility is forgetting to "
*export* PYTHONPATH.

```
> cat .bash_profile
# -----
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/me/pythondir:/home/me/other
export PYTHONPATH
# -----
```